# Get data with Ajax sequentially with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, q

I have to load from the API 3 different things:

- users
- groups
- messages

Actually what I did is:

```
var loadAll = $q.all([
    getUsers.all(),
    getGroups.all(),
    getMessages.all()
]);

loadAll.then(function (data) {
    $scope.users = data[0];
    $scope.groups = data[1];
    $scope.messages = data[2];
};
```

It is working fine but unfortunately it load users, groups and messages not in the order I wish...

What I wish to do is to load users, then load the groups and finally load the messages.

I can not understand exactly how to do that correctly...

My services return promises:

```
getUsers.all()
.then(function(data) {
    $scope.users = data;
};
```

But if I do:

```
getUsers.all()
.then(function(data) {
    $scope.users = data;
    getGroups.all()
    .then(function(data) {
        // etc...
    }
};
```

It resolve the promises as soon as users has been loaded without waiting for others...

How can I do it?

Comment: Really not clear what the issue is. Do you need the `users` data to do something with `groups`? The second version makes the requests in order as you are asking for

Comment: *"It is working fine but unfortunately it load users, groups and messages not in the order I wish..."* you mean the `data` array is out of order? or what.

Comment: I need to load first all users, then all groups, then all messages. Using q.all do not work like that... If I have 1000 users and 30 groups it will load first the groups... because faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chaining the promises to load the datasets sequentially should work :

```
getUsers.all().then(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data
        return getGroups.all()
}).then(function(data) {
        $scope.groups = data
        return getMessages.all()
}).then(function(data) {
        $scope.messages = data
});
```

this  because `then` returns a promise.

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo glad to know that helped you out !